# Trying to write multiple lines to a file from a struct in C

Tags: c, file, struct

i'm writing a small program thats outputs student data to text file, I store this data in a struct array, then i try to output this data to a text file; But for some reason it only outputs the most recent inputted data.

```
struct students
{
    char *familyName[20], *firstName[20];
    int enrolNum, mark1, mark2, mark3;
} st[1000];

FILE *fptr;
int studentNum;
int i = 0;
void main()
{
    double markOne, markTwo, markThree;

    markOne = st[i].mark1 * 0.30;
    markTwo = st[i].mark2 * 0.40;
    markThree = st[i].mark3 * 0.30;
    char *fName;
    do
    {
        ptr = fopen("student.txt", "a+");
        fprintf(fptr, "Family name \tFirst name \tenrolment number \tartefact mark 1 \tartefact mark 2 \tartefact mark 3 \n");
        fprintf(fptr,"%s \t\t%s \t\t%d \t\t\t%.1f%% \t\t%.1f%%  \t\t%.1f%% \n", st[i].familyName, st[i].firstName, st[i].enrolNum, markOne, markTwo, markThree);
        printf("\n%d\n%d", i, studentNum);
    } while( i < studentNum);
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why it only outputs the most recent data point and not all of it.
any hints as to why it would do this?

Many thanks 
Steve

Comment: `ptr = fopen("student.txt", "a+");` should really be done once outside the loop. If you really must open inside the loop then also close inside the loop.

Comment: Why are the `st` values never actually set?

Comment: `char *familyName[20], *firstName[20];` probably needs to be `char familyName[20], firstName[20];`.

Comment: The St values are inputted by the user in a different part of the program. If you would like to see the whole program i could add it.

Comment: No I don't need to see that. But it would be good to mention such things in your post so that people know it's intentionally left out and don't need to focus on it (many SO posts have code that uses uninitialised variables).

Comment: Unless you are on a *freestanding* system (without an OS), then `void main()` is wrong. Where does `i` change?

Comment: I increments upwards as data is added to the struct. but, doing the `ptr = fopen("student.txt", "a+");`out side the loop seems to of fixed the problem i had. it was outputting all first names i put into the system. Thank you Kaylum for that. Although now i feel incredibly dumb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the line `ptr = fopen("student.txt", "a+");` outside the loop. You will gel what you want.

```
struct students
{
    char *familyName[20], *firstName[20];
    int enrolNum, mark1, mark2, mark3;
} st[1000];

FILE *fptr;
int studentNum;
int i = 0;
void main()
{
    double markOne, markTwo, markThree;

    markOne = st[i].mark1 * 0.30;
    markTwo = st[i].mark2 * 0.40;
    markThree = st[i].mark3 * 0.30;
    char *fName;
    ptr = fopen("student.txt", "a+");
    do
    {

        fprintf(fptr, "Family name \tFirst name \tenrolment number \tartefact mark 1 \tartefact mark 2 \tartefact mark 3 \n");
        fprintf(fptr,"%s \t\t%s \t\t%d \t\t\t%.1f%% \t\t%.1f%%  \t\t%.1f%% \n", st[i].familyName, st[i].firstName, st[i].enrolNum, markOne, markTwo, markThree);
        printf("\n%d\n%d", i, studentNum);
    } while( i < studentNum);
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

The problem with your code is that `ptr = fopen("student.txt", "a+");` is getting called every time the loop is executing. And the file `ptr` is opened again. It has not been closed during previous iteration.
If you add `fclose(fptr);` in the loop, it will also work.